# linux firewall as a router in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos7

In our setup we have a linux server with 2 physical NICs(eth0,eth1) and 2 virtual windows machines. 1 nic(eth0) is connected to VM1(vnet0) and other (eth1)is connected to VM2(vnet1). eth0 and vnet1 is making a bridge(br0) and eth1 and vnet1 is making a bridge(br1). Now, we want to take rdp of VM2 from VM1.  So, could anybody please tell me what rules we need to make in firewalld so that traffic can go from VM1 -> linux firewall -> VM2.

Check image for better explanation:

[image]

Comment: Your question is very messy and it's hard to read - would you re-format/clarify it so your situation will be more understandable?

Comment: Hi arieljannai, I have edited my question and added a pictorial representation. I hop this will make you understand. and thank you so much for the help.

Comment: is the Linux Firewall the host for the Windows virtual machines?

Comment: Hi Bert, Yes the host machine is Linux(CentOS) and on that two windows virtual machines are running. i just want to take my all traffic from first virtual machine which is on left side and in br0 bridge to second virtual machine which is on right side and in br1 bridge. My linux firewall should work as router so that it can route traffic from br0 to br1. Also, both bridges are in different network

Comment: Well, if you are using KVM and you have a GUI, you always can create a new network and assign that to the two interfaces. However, keep in mind, that this will mean the 2 VMs will be able to communicate but noone else is allowed to talk in that network. Honestly, why would you put VMs on a Firewall computer?

Comment: Hi Bert, now my machines can communicate each other. last question, could you please tell me the rule in firewalld as i am using Centos7 so that my 1st virtual machine do ssh of second and my second machine block the traffic on port 80 from 1st virtual machine.. and thanks in advance

Comment: i got the result by using DIRECT rules.